# Find and copy all data from the last 10 days within string

Tags: python-3.x

The code below is my complete program to date:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re
import pprint

#Falchion Knife Stained (Minimum Wear)
falchion_stained_MW = 'http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/%E2%98%85%20Falchion%20Knife%20%7C%20Stained%20%28Minimal%20Wear%29'

values = {'s':'basics',
          'submit':'search'}

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
data = data.encode('utf-8')
req = urllib.request.Request(falchion_stained_MW, data)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
falchion_stained_MW_respdata = resp.read()
#pprint.pprint(falchion_stained_MW_respdata)


Unfiltered_Item_Trade_History = re.findall(r"\[\"\w{3}\s\d{2}\s\d{4}\s\d{2}:\s\+\d\"\,\d{1,3}\.\d{1,4}\,\"\d\"\]",str(falchion_stained_MW_respdata))
Unfiltered_Item_Trade_History_String = str(Unfiltered_Item_Trade_History)
Item_Trade_History1 = Unfiltered_Item_Trade_History_String.replace('["', "")
Item_Trade_History2 = re.sub(r'\s\d{2}\:\s\+\d\"\,', ": $", Item_Trade_History1)
Item_Trade_History3 = re.sub(r'\,\"\d\"\]', "", Item_Trade_History2)
Item_Trade_History4 = Item_Trade_History3.replace(r"[", "")
Item_Trade_History = Item_Trade_History4.replace(r"]", "")
#print(Item_Trade_History)


Current_Date = datetime.now()
Date_10_Days_Ago = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=10)

item_sales = [sale.split(': +0",') for sale in Item_Trade_History]
sales_10_days = [float(sale[1]) for sale in item_sales if datetime.strptime(sale[0], '%b %d %Y') - Date_10_Days_Ago > timedelta(days=0)]
print(sales_10_days)
```

The line of code "Unfiltered_Item_Trade_History" prints the following. This data is in original form and is exactly what the website provides me when scraped:

['["Sep 15 2016 16: +0",40.434,"2"]', '["Sep 15 2016 18: +0",42.556,"1"]', '["Sep 16 2016 05: +0",43.482,"1"]', '["Sep 16 2016 12: +0",43.129,"1"]', '["Sep 16 2016 14: +0",41.289,"1"]', '["Sep 16 2016 18: +0",40.67,"1"]', '["Sep 16 2016 19: +0",41.902,"2"]', '["Sep 16 2016 23: +0",41.4,"1"]', '["Sep 17 2016 02: +0",43.495,"1"]', '["Sep 17 2016 04: +0",43.562,"1"]', '["Sep 17 2016 07: +0",44.009,"1"]', '["Sep 17 2016 13: +0",44.674,"2"]', '["Sep 17 2016 17: +0",42.222,"1"]', '["Sep 18 2016 00: +0",40.882,"1"]', '["Sep 18 2016 08: +0",39.094,"1"]', '["Sep 18 2016 11: +0",40.211,"1"]', '["Sep 18 2016 12: +0",41.088,"1"]', '["Sep 18 2016 14: +0",44.571,"2"]', '["Sep 18 2016 17: +0",36.23,"1"]', '["Sep 18 2016 20: +0",41.34,"1"]', '["Sep 18 2016 23: +0",36.6,"1"]', '["Sep 19 2016 00: +0",39.999,"1"]', '["Sep 19 2016 14: +0",40.636,"1"]', '["Sep 19 2016 15: +0",40.009,"1"]', '["Sep 19 2016 16: +0",38.625,"1"]', '["Sep 19 2016 17: +0",39.101,"1"]', '["Sep 19 2016 18: +0",39.361,"2"]']

The next line of code "Unfilitered_Item_Trade_History_String" returns the same list as above but in string form.

IN order to get it to the format you have written below, I have to use all the lines above + Item_Trade_History1 to 4. This code removes all of the extra characters and adds the $ dollar sign where it's needed. Once I get to the final line of code "Item_Trade_History" it returns the following list:

'Sep 15 2016: $40.434', 'Sep 15 2016: $42.556', 'Sep 16 2016: $43.482', 'Sep 16 2016: $43.129', 'Sep 16 2016: $41.289', 'Sep 16 2016: $40.67', 'Sep 16 2016: $41.902', 'Sep 16 2016: $41.4', 'Sep 17 2016: $43.495', 'Sep 17 2016: $43.562', 'Sep 17 2016: $44.009', 'Sep 17 2016: $44.674', 'Sep 17 2016: $42.222', 'Sep 18 2016: $40.882', 'Sep 18 2016: $39.094', 'Sep 18 2016: $40.211', 'Sep 18 2016: $41.088', 'Sep 18 2016: $44.571', 'Sep 18 2016: $36.23', 'Sep 18 2016: $41.34', 'Sep 18 2016: $36.6', 'Sep 19 2016: $39.999', 'Sep 19 2016: $40.636', 'Sep 19 2016: $40.009', 'Sep 19 2016: $38.625', 'Sep 19 2016: $39.101', 'Sep 19 2016: $39.361'

This returned list is identical to the list you have added below, correct?

Now I added the modification you've given me to my code.

"item_sales = [sale.split(": $") for sale in Item_Trade_History[1:len(Item_Trade_History) - 1].split("','")]"

and printed "item_sales" which returns this:

[['Sep 15 2016", "42.27', 'Sep 15 2016", "43.337', 'Sep 15 2016", "40.434', 'Sep 15 2016", "42.556', 'Sep 16 2016", "43.482', 'Sep 16 2016", "43.129', 'Sep 16 2016", "41.289', 'Sep 16 2016", "40.67', 'Sep 16 2016", "41.902', 'Sep 16 2016", "41.4', 'Sep 17 2016", "43.495', 'Sep 17 2016", "43.562', 'Sep 17 2016", "44.009', 'Sep 17 2016", "44.674', 'Sep 17 2016", "42.222', 'Sep 18 2016", "40.882', 'Sep 18 2016", "39.094', 'Sep 18 2016", "40.211', 'Sep 18 2016", "41.088', 'Sep 18 2016", "44.571', 'Sep 18 2016", "36.23', 'Sep 18 2016", "41.34', 'Sep 18 2016", "36.6', 'Sep 19 2016", "39.999', 'Sep 19 2016", "40.636', 'Sep 19 2016", "40.009', 'Sep 19 2016", "38.625', 'Sep 19 2016", "39.101', 'Sep 19 2016", '39.361']]

Now we got it to separate the stuff, does this look correct? We are getting close man!!!!

OK, now when I use the last line of code:

sales_10_days = [float(sale[1]) for sale in item_sales if datetime.strptime(sale[0], '%b %d %Y') - Date_10_Days_Ago > timedelta(days=0)]

and print "sales_10_days" it returns:

[]

At least there is no error!!! But why is the last bit of code not working? We are so close I can taste it. You have no idea how much I appreciate you man. Thank you so much for all of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with loops? Or, to be more pythonic, you could use list comprehension.

Example:

```
item_sales = [sale.split(": $") for sale in item_sales_data[1:len(item_sales_data) - 1].split("','")]
sales_10_days = [float(sale[1]) for sale in item_sales if datetime.strptime(sale[0], "%b %d %Y") - Date_10_Days_ago > timedelta(days=0)]
```

Note: to use datetime.strptime you can use from datetime import datetime or use datetime.datetime.strptime instead.

Edit: To apply to the data in the original format you can do this:

```
import json
#Parse each sub array that is in JSON format
item_sales_data = [json.loads(sale) for sale in Unfiltered_Item_Trade_History]
#Trim the timezone information out of dates since it is not in a strptime friendly format
item_sales = [[sale[0][:len(sale[0]) - 4], sale[1]] for sale in item_sales_data]
#Filter the list and return only the prices from the last 10 days
sales_10_days = [sale[1] for sale in item_sales if datetime.strptime(sale[0], "%b %d %Y %H") - Date_10_Days_ago > timedelta(days=0)]
```

Comment: Hey man! Thank you as well for your time! I really appreciate it. I have nothing against loops, I am just unsure how to go about it. If that is the best way, than I am all for it! I am sorry I am just a bit new to the whole thing. Anyways, I went ahead and implemented your code. For what ever reason I am getting the error "TypeError: unorderable types: datetime.timedelta() > int()'. I'm unsure what it means as I am fairly new, any ideas on what the issue could be?

Comment: Just so you know, the "TypeError: unorderable types" error refers to the part `datetime.strptime(sale[0], "%b %d %Y") - Date_10_Days_ago > 0`. This is because the relationship between ints and timedeltas is not defined in python.

Comment: hey man! Thank you so much for your time. I truly appreciate it. I am closer than ever, I can feel it. The code that you gave me returns zero errors, BUT it also returns only empty brackets []. If I had to take a guess, It seems like the program isn't treating the dates as dates. I went ahead and updated my code above to my full program. You are going to laugh at it I'm sure, there's alot of duplicate code and things I should've done differently but just didn't know how. If you can spot the problem, I will be eternally grateful. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Also, I had to add the final "Sub" function to remove a extra apostrophe, This would be line 'Item_Trade_History = Item_Trade_History5.replace(r"'", "")' Otherwise it wouldn't run and would return the error "Time Data " ' Aug 12 2016" does not match format "%b %d %Y". That is the only way I know how to get rid of that extra apostrophe.

Comment: If you want to go about it differently, just delete the line above and change the line above it from "Item_Trade_History5" to "Item_Trade_History". Then the code will function but with the extra apostrophe (and will throw errors at the end)

Comment: I've also tried adding the apostrophe to the date format, which makes the program return zero errors but also empty brackets. Just figured I'd throw that out there too :)

Comment: Yes, the problem here is that the data isn't in the same format as it originally was anymore. With my method you don't need to use the replace/etc to clean up the source string: just use it directly. Alternatively, you can change the first line to `item_sales = [sale.split(": $") for sale in item_sales_history]` to work with the new list format.

Comment: Well, The original data looks something like this: '["Sep 19 2016 18: +0",39.361,"2"]']. I've tried adding these extra characters to the code and it says "ValueError: unconverted data remains:  01" and that is from the original data. I have changed the split data to reflect what it says now which is how I got it to throw that error, otherwise it just says time data does not match format. I am very lost on how your code actually works, please forgive me. If you are willing to help me out a bit more I will tip you $10 in Bitcoin. If it'd be easier I have a email/skype.

Comment: I see. I'm still unsure of the exact data format so I'll explain my code. First, list comprehension in python means that `[item for item in otherlist]` results in a list of item. I use this to transform each item in list by splitting the date from the dollar format. This gets me a list of lists in this form: `[[Date_String, Price_String]]`. I then use the second list comprehension to take the second element of each sub array `Price_String` and add it to a new list if the first element `Date_String` is less than 10 days ago.

Comment: To determine if `Date_string` is less than 10 days ago I use `datetime`'s `strptime` parser and the format `"%b %d %Y"`. This format means the string must be in a form like "sep 02 2012". But in your data the structure is "sep 02 2012 02: +0". ie, you need the format string `"%b %d %Y %H: +0"`. The +0 in the string is likely a timezone indicator but strptime in python does not support that format. You can use the literal if it's predictable. You can read more on formatting options [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Comment: Thank you for typing that out, It definitely makes sense now. I just can't seem to understand why it won't recognize the format. I've tried so many things now. "%b %d %IY %H: +0",  "%b %d %Y" , "['%b %d %Y %H: +0",  "['%b %d %Y". I've tried removing all these characters, I've tried adding them to the format. No matter what, it's always an error code stating that the format doesn't match. Have you tried running the lower code above in IDLE? I think you will see what i mean. If you get it to work, I will tip you, because at this point, I'm at your mercy.

Comment: Yes, using the format `item_sales_data = 'Sep 15 2016: $42.27', 'Sep 15 2016: $43.337', 'Sep 15 2016: $40.434', 'Sep 15 2016: $42.556'...` I have gotten the results `[42.27, 43.337, 40.434, 42.556, 43.482, 43.129, 41.289, 40.67, 41.902, 41.4, 43.495, 43.562, 44.009, 44.674, 42.222, 40.882, 39.094, 40.211, 41.088, 44.571, 36.23]` using the modification `item_sales = [sale.split(": $") for sale in item_sales_history]`. If you can get the data to that format then it should work as written. Otherwise, I will need a more comprehensive example of the original format of the data.

Comment: OK, I went ahead and edited my whole first post. It will show a step by step guide through what's going on in my code, showing what each line of code returns. Please check the original first post on this page for the new edited information in regards to this issue. Again, I thank you so much for your time. I will totally tip you man!

Comment: The edit implies that it's being passed a string. So just one correction: use `item_sales = [sale.split(": $") for sale in item_sales_data[1:len(item_sales_data) - 1].split("','")]` instead on the same string.

Comment: Oh man!!! We are getting close!!! Ok. I added the line above and it returns: [['Sep 15 2016", "42.27', 'Sep 15 2016", "43.337', 'Sep 15 2016", "40.434']]. Its SOOO CLOSE!! Now when I run the final bit of code, it returns empty brackets "[]". No errors!! I'm happy just to see that. What is going on with the last bit? I will update the top post now

Comment: OK man, I went ahead and updated the top post for you, it's a bit more complete than my comment above. Again, thank you so much you have no idea how much I appreciate your help! You are a saint.

Comment: I've edited my post above to apply the solution directly to the original data format. It should work without the need for the extra string parsing done in the Item_Trade_History lines. See the second code snippet.

Comment: That would be awesome, but the code is from HTML data and I'm not making JSON calls, does that matter? I tried the code but am getting errors again :(. Is there no way to get the other one working? I will add an update for the code you provided me if you'd rather work with that one. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps it is not being applied to the correct data. Try replacing `falchion_strained_MW` with `Unfiltered_Item_Trade_History` since I worked from what is actually the output of that variable. What you are getting appears to be in JSON format so it's fine to use the JSON parser in this case as long as you can guarantee the format will be in that format for any input.

Comment: Awesome that is good to know tbh, I always thought it would be particular. I am glad to know that. I am giving it a shot now, and also trying to update my main OP.

Comment: OMG man it worked@@. I seriously can't thank you enough, wow was that one a doosy!! You are a true saint for helping me out for so long. Had i known I should've gone about it this way from the get go, I would have. Please, provide me with a bitcoin address, I will send you a tip as soon as I crack my wallet open, should take 15 minutes or less. I'd shake your hand if I could!!

Comment: No worries. Don't worry about the tip. Accepting my answer is enough.

Comment: Seriously man, you've made my day. This has been a nut i've been trying to crack for nearly 3 days now. Thanks again. I really appreciate you spending so much time for random me on the internet. I am eternally grateful! haha :P You take care of yourself. If you change your mind about that tip, you know where to find me :)

Comment: ooo got cha, done :) The least I can do. Learn something new every day haha.

Answer (score 0):

split `'date: price'` to `[date, price]`, then compare date and `Date_10_Days_Ago`, get the list of from the last 10 days and order them by date .

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

item_sales_data = 'Sep 15 2016: $42.27','Sep 15 2016: $43.337', 'Sep 15 2016: $40.434','Sep 15 2016: $42.556', 'Sep 16 2016: $43.482','Sep 16 2016: $43.129', 'Sep 16 2016: $41.289','Sep 16 2016: $40.67', 'Sep 16 2016: $41.902','Sep 16 2016: $41.4', 'Sep 17 2016: $43.495', 'Sep 17 2016: $43.562', 'Sep 17 2016: $44.009', 'Sep 17 2016: $44.674', 'Sep 17 2016: $42.222', 'Sep 18 2016: $40.882', 'Sep 18 2016: $39.094', 'Sep 18 2016: $40.211','Sep 18 2016: $41.088', 'Sep 18 2016: $44.571', 'Sep 18 2016: $36.23'

Date_10_Days_Ago = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=10)

# split 'Sep 15 2016: $42.27' to (date('Sep 15 2016'), '$42.27')
date_prices = [data.split(": ") for data in item_sales_data if datetime.strptime(data.split(": ")[0], "%b %d %Y") > Date_10_Days_Ago]



# sort date_prices by date
def dateKey(data):
    return datetime.strptime(data[0], "%b %d %Y")

date_prices.sort(key=dateKey, reverse=True)

# only need prices
prices = [p[1] for p in date_prices]
print(prices)
```

Comment: re-edit: Thank you so much for your help! I love your ideas, I just didn't know how to wrap my head around it. Anyways, the comment before was wrong, I had the wrong list added, so it was giving me the wrong error message. I am currently getting a error message that says "time data '[' does not match format '%b %d %Y'. I have looked through the code but can't seem to find anything obvious popping out as a typo, any ideas what is causing this issue? Thanks for your time!!

Comment: you can reduce `item_sales_data `,  just like : `item_sales_data = ('Sep 15 2016: $42.27','Sep 15 2016: $43.337')`  this can help you to judge if the mistake is the time Format.

Comment: I can't seem to find any typos, I am very confused on it. It is basically saying that it can't use Timedelta with a interger. My time data is a string. I'm very lost on how to continue, sorry. I appreciate your help though.

Comment: I can't even find the same error online to research it haha. TypeError: unorderable types: datetime.timedelta() > int(). I have no clue what it means. I will edit my post so it shows my current code with your implementations

Comment: OK，show me your current code in your post,  i will get back to you ASAP.

Comment: why your data `Sep 15 2016: $42.27` not in quotes ?  just like:`'Sep 15 2016: $42.27'`, more clearly: `Item_Trade_History = ('Sep 07 2016: $41.986', 'Sep 07 2016: $40.89')`

Comment: Sorry, I can change that. I had them removed because the error before I had them in there was: Time data " ' " does not match format "%b %d %Y". So I changed it so it would remove the apostrophes. I can remove the re.sub function for that particular part in my true code. That is just an example list as the real list is pulled from data from a site and has re.sub/replace functions removing much of the junk to the left/right of it.

Comment: if the the `Item_Trade_History` just is `('Sep 07 2016: $41.986', 'Sep 07 2016: $40.89')` , only two strings, can it run correctly ?

Comment: OK man, I updated it. It throws an error code: ValueError: time data "'May 27 2015" does not match format '%b %d %Y' - There is an extra apostrophe, that's why I was trying to get rid of them, haha.

Comment: No, It throws an error code: ValueError: time data "'May 27 2015" does not match format '%b %d %Y'

Comment: Data cleaning…… `data.split(": ")[0].replace("'","")` remove them( `'` etc.) by `replace`

Comment: OK I will give that a shot and report back to you. Thanks again for your help, I really really really appreciate it. Truly. I must sleep soon because I have to work tomorrow, but I will respond again in the AM and let you know what I figure out. Have a great night man! Take care !

Comment: Hey man, so I went ahead and gave the data cleaning a shot. It still is giving me an error though. For what ever reason when I add that code, it says "ValueError: time data "'" does not match format '%b %d %Y'" and It should;ve removed the apostrophe and now there's nothing but an apostrophe.

Comment: Sorry, man…… i really don't know why.....suggest you do some unit tests, tests every parts of you code

Comment: No worries man, thanks anyways! I ended up going about it differently using JSON code and it worked better than what I was trying anyways. I am just a noob and had no idea how to go about it so I did what I do best and made things as difficult as possible. haha. Thanks for your time, I truly appreciate it. Have a nice day!